# Only 1 of 2 monitors is detected by Windows after restart / sleep

Tags: display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-quadro, windows-10-pro

Every time a specific computer is restarted, only the main display comes back on automatically, and to get the other one on the user has to manually unplug and replug the video connector from the back of the computer.

The PC is running the newest version of Windows 10 Pro, and has a Nvidia Quadro P2000. I have just recently done a clean install of the most recent drivers, which didn't fix the problem.

The monitors are plugged in with DVI to DisplayPort adapters. Unfortunately, there isn't another way to plug it in, as the monitors only have VGA and DVI, and the graphics card only has DisplayPort.

I have tried switching the cables, the graphics card, and everything on the software side I could think of. Any suggestions on what to try next? I'm pretty sure it's a software issue since changing the hardware did nothing, but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: What's "everything on the software side"? Be **as specific as possible** please so that people won't give you repeated advices.

Comment: Well I'd be happy to get a single answer at this point. But running troubleshooters, trying different versions of the drivers, setting high performance power mode, running DISM and sfc /scannow, I'm kinda just trying random stuff cause I'm not sure what the root problem is. I also made sure windows is up to date. We have 2 other systems with the exact same setup and they haven't had any similar problems

Comment: Please edit the question with additional info instead of only commenting it. You could also try e.g. if it happens on any other system, if you install one, to debug further. Then you'll know if it's software or hardware issue, both have a bunch of possibilities you didn't eliminate, still. If it turns out to be system/software, Windows repair install or complete reinstall may be the best step then, otherwise you could check Windows event log for anything interesting (especially errors), try resetting your power plan, downgrading/upgrading your BIOS, etc.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help though. "bunch of possibilities you didn't eliminate" that's why I was asking on here, to get new troubleshooting options I couldn't think of. I know I was missing things, but what?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download driver and DDU

Disconnect the NETWORK Cable

Safe boot windows

Run DDU with these settings:
NVIDIA Software and drivers
Clean, do not restart

Install, Shutdown and Reboot

Install the NVIDIA driver with these options
Custom, Uncheck Everything except the GPU driver, clean install

Reboot

Reconnect the Ethernet

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1184562)

Comment: @RohitGupta Just fixed my answer

Comment: Also, cioudn't you just use `rapr.exe` to remove the obsolete display driver(s)?

Comment: @Arctiic this is the first I've hear of rapr, but it sounds like it would have worked as well